# Как назвать запирающее бутылку приспособление?

Tags: названия

Как назвать такую обтяжку (шпагат) на крышке бутылки? Замок или клапан?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это защитный бутылочный датчик — часто его называют противокражным (антикражным).

Радиочастотный **датчик для бутылок** — это эффективная защита против краж.
Датчик выполнен по образцу **хомута**: крепится к горлышку бутылки жестким тросом, снять который можно, только используя магнитный съемник. Чтобы стекло бутылки не раздавила твердая поверхность, **тросик** защищен мягкой прозрачной оболочкой.
Датчик предотвращает вскрытие и переливание содержимого бутылок, защищает товары с любой формой горлышка — при этом упаковка и акцизная марка не повреждается.

[Датчик для бутылок](http://sao96.ru/bottle-tag-akustomagnitnyy-butylochnyy-datchik-dlya-alkogolya)